# replace values in column in data frame with average value

Tags: dataframe, replace

I am working with data analysis using python. I want to replace all data `< 120` in one column with average_steam. average_steam= 123
to access the column in data frame I write "data.steam" then I get all values

the code I tried is:

```py
average_steam=data.steamin.mean()
print(average_steam)

 data.steamin.replace(data.steamin<=120,average_steam, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Are you asking to replace all numerical values LESS then 120 with average_steam? so if you have three values, 90, 123, 1 after the replacement the 3 items will look like this? average_steam, 123, average_steam? If you could include what this data looked like, whether it's CSV or array, or something similar it will help to understand what you are looking for. Need more detail in other words.

Comment: @caperneoignis yes, I want to replace all numerical values less than 120 with an average value calculated from same column in csv. I imported a CSV file as pd and got a complete table. to call the data frame I write `data` then i get the data file. to call one column I write `data.steam` and to calculate average value for the column I write `average_steam=data.steam.mean()` then`print average_steam`which returns 123. so I want all values in column steam less than 120 to be replaced by 123. i.e if i have 12, 90, 130, 128,110 I want to get  123,123,130,128, 123.