# Replace all numerical values in a column in a data frame Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

*I want to replace all numerical values less than 120 with an average value calculated from same column in csv. I imported a CSV file as pd and got a complete table. to call the data frame I write data then I get the data file. to call one column I write data.steam and to calculate average value for the column I write average_steam=data.steam.mean() then print average_steam which returns 123. So, I want all values in column steam less than 120 to be replaced by 123. i.e if I have 12, 90, 130, 128,110 I want to get 123,123,130,128, 123. 
All necessary libraries are imported.*

The code I tried:

```
data.steam 
average_steam=data.steam.mean() 
print average_steam
data.steamin.replace(data.steamin<=120,average_steam, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Your answer should work for Python 3 at least. I just tried it.

Comment: What's wrong with that code? Also, why are you using Python 2?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [replace values in column in data frame with average value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60341417/replace-values-in-column-in-data-frame-with-average-value)

Comment: This is a duplicate of a question you already asked. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60341417/replace-values-in-column-in-data-frame-with-average-value)

Answer (score 1):

If `df` is Your `pd.DataFrame` and `x`is column to modify then try:

```
df.x[df.x<120]=df.x.mean()
```

Comment: This is wrong. It will replace all columns instead of just the column x. You should replace the first df with df.x

Answer (score 1):

This was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31511997/pandas-dataframe-replace-all-values-in-a-column-based-on-condition).

In your case, it would be:

```
data.loc[data['steam'] < 120, 'steam'] = average_steam
```

Here is what is happening:

by using `data.loc` you are choosing some rows and columns. The first argument in `loc` is the rows. You are choosing rows where the value in the `steam` column is less than 120. The second argument is the columns. In your case you are choosing `steam` as your column. So you are choosing all rows in the column `steam` with a value less than 120. And then your are assigning to these cells the value `average_steam`.